# Как сделать, чтобы бот не реагировал на пользователя, у которого роль = боту или выше его?

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
import disnake
from disnake.ext import commands
import asyncio

...

@bot.slash_command(name="localban", description="Локальная блокировка за крупное нарушение")
async def lban(ctx, member : disnake.Member, time = None, reason = None):       
        if member == ctx.author:
            embed1 = disnake.Embed(title='Локальный бан', description=f'Невозможно заблокировать самого себя.', color=color)
            embed1.set_footer(text=footer, icon_url=bot_icon)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed1)
            endif

    #пытался сделать так:
    if ctx.member.role >= ctx.bot.role
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой метод. Это обычная проверка на то, вызвала ли функция ошибку или продолжила работу.

```
    try:
        #ваша функция бана, например: await member.ban
    except:
        #обработка ошибки
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Я не могу забанить этого пользователя.")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return
    #если ошибок не возникло
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Вы забанили пользователя ...")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    return
```